# How to prevent rewriting input variable in a function?

Tags: python, variables, local

I'm trying to write a function that takes a list as an input and returns a modified version of that list such that the function does not change the input list.  The input variable T is a list of lists.  I have tried

```
def function(T):
  Tree = copy.copy(T)
  Do stuff with Tree
  return Tree
```

only to discover that `T` has been changed by the function.  I have also tried `Tree = T[:]`  but that also doesn't work.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Likely the issue is you require a *deep* copy of the items in T (presumably, some sort of Node object). When you use a shallow copy, i.e. `copy.copy` or `my_list.copy()` or `my_list[:]` then the *list* is copied but the items inside the list are not.

Comment: This worked perfectly.  THANK YOU!!!